# Fibonnaci.java and runner

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

I'm having trouble working on this assignment and could use some help Here are the instructions with sample input and output included:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nawNh.png . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FibonacciRunner
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fibArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,11,16,21,31,41,46,1,1,2,1,2,11};
        Fibonacci fibo = new Fibonacci();
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());

    }
}
```

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    int[] fibArray;
    public Fibonacci()
    {
        fibArray = new int[50];
        this.setFibo();
    }
    public void setFibo()
    {
        fibArray[0]=1;
        fibArray[1]=1;
        for(int idx = 2; idx<fibArray.length; idx++){
            fibArray[idx] = fibArray[idx-1] + fibArray[idx-2];
        }

    }
    public int getFibo(int index)
    {
    if(index < 50)
     return fibArray[index];
    else
      return -1;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.getFibo() + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: getFibo takes an int, but you call it with no parameters. This would be a compiler error. for(int I=0; I< 50; I++) System.out.println(fibo.getFibo(I)); might be a clue

Answer (score 0):

Ashley is right.  You should be doing something like this in the main program:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fibArray.length; i++ )
    System.out.println(fibo.getFibo(fibArray[i]));
```